# Show x-axis values as my x has different ranges

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I trying to plot my data in python using the `matplotlib` library. My data:

`x =[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]`

I tried `plt.xticks(x)` but as the values between 2 and 10 have different ranges than from 10 to 100, the former get too squeezed.

I also tried `plt.xticks(range(len(x)),x)` but that is even worse: *all* x-axis values are squeezed.

What I want is a tick for each value in my x regardless of the different range between the values.

Any help with that, please?

Comment: you want the `x-ticks` in the plot as your `x` list?

Comment: Yes exactly @Thinker